# what port does the socketIO client listen to by default?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

When you do not specify a port in the io.connect() function on the client side, what port does the client listen to?

eg:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com/'); // listening to port 80?
```

The reason I ask is because I deployed the server side of this application on heroku. The front end is an IOS application. The objective C socketIO library I'm using for the front end (https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) requires me to specify a port. But I'm not sure what port I should listen to since this is not static on the server side.

I wrote client program in javascript for testing and it works when I do not specify a port.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If 80 works, then it's 80.  Why not just try it?

Comment: So you're saying that when you do not specify a port, then its using port 80? Port 80 was my guess, I don't know this for sure.

Comment: I think the Express server listens on port 3000 by default.

Comment: On Heroku it doesn't though. You use an environment variable to specify the port. It is not a static thing.

example: 
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(port);'

Comment: @Mash I checked, port 80 doesn't work

Comment: @SivaDotRender how would you get the port number that the client had connected to on the client side assuming a dynamic port used by heroku?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It listens on the port the server listens to. Imagine you set your server to listen port `8080`. Then you load your page at `http://localhost:8080` and the server returns the page which contains the socket related JS code.

1. If you don't specify any port or host as in `var socket = io.connect();`, it defaults to the host and port of the current page.
2. If you specify only the host which is same as the current host, it defaults to the port of the current host.
3. If you specify only the host which is different from the current host, it defaults to port `80` if the protocol is HTTP. If the protocol is HTTPS, then the port defaults to `443`.

Here is the related code for [url.js](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/url.js#L24) parser.

Comment: I am guessing that you mean local host by current host? (I am not very familiar with this terminology). Also what do you mean by current page? I checked the url.js file you linked me to and the rest of your answer seems to be correct.

Comment: Current host isn't necessarily he local host. Imagine you're loading your page from http://apple.com. This is you current page. If you're loading the http://apple.com/mac, this is your current page. It refers to the page loaded at this moment.