# vue.js / socket.io: 404 errors in JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

The frontend part of my app is making requests such as these:

```
GET http://lizardgizzards.com:4001/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Megqhnd 404 (Not Found)
h.create @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
h @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
u.request @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
u.doPoll @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
h.poll @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
h.doOpen @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
i.open @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
h.open @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
h @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
h @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
l.open.l.connect @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
l @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
l @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
c @ vue-socketio.js?5132:8
value @ vue-socketio.js?5132:10
t @ vue-socketio.js?5132:10
(anonymous) @ main.js?56d7:6
./src/main.js @ app.js:2059
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:724
fn @ app.js:101
1 @ app.js:2085
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:724
(anonymous) @ app.js:791
(anonymous) @ app.js:794
```

I'm running Express on the backend.

The Express log output (not too long ago the output was showing 200s instead of 404s):

```
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Megrimu 404 0.962 ms - 2200
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MegrkOq 404 0.990 ms - 2200
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Megrm6D 404 0.979 ms - 2200
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Megrnpa 404 0.931 ms - 2200
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MegrpWz 404 1.691 ms - 2200
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MegrrEK 404 0.990 ms - 2200
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Megrsxi 404 0.961 ms - 2200
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Megruf6 404 0.933 ms - 2200
```

I've added a basic socket.io codeblock on the backend, so that socket.io connections should hopefully go through. The below code I added simply as a placeholder.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: socket.io runs on a different port; in one of my apps I have a line like this: `const server = io('http://server:8080');` so the client-side `io` properly connects to the socket server, not the web server.

Comment: socket.io (on the server side) doesn't run on the same port that my express server is running on?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778414/what-port-does-the-socketio-client-listen-to-by-default) says that socket.io (on the server) listens on the same port the server is running on.

Comment: You're right, you don't have to use two ports. Can you show your server-side setup? It should look something like [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io#in-conjunction-with-express).

Comment: Here's my Express `app.js`: https://github.com/brlafreniere/vue-chat-app/blob/master/backend/app.js

Comment: You have two `server`s: one in `app.js` which you connect to `io`, a second one in `bin/www` which is the one that listens to incoming calls. Move your socket.io setup to `bin/www`.